# How To Convert The String (X cm) To INT (X) X = Number

Tags: c#, string, int

How To Convert The String (X LE) To INT (X)

X = Number

I used :

```
Convert.ToInt32(Form1.sendproductprice1)*Convert.ToInt32(Form1.sendamount));
```

Example :

```
Form1.sendproductprice1   =  "25 LE";
Form1.sendamount = 5;
```

Then value must be 125

But I got Error "Input string was not in correct format"

Comment: Please, format a posted code properly so that your question is more readable. There is a button in the editor which looks like `{ }`. Just select your text, press the button and that's all.

Comment: You have to take the substring with the numbers. And shouldn't the value be 125 ? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code below should be work:

```
Convert.ToInt32(Form1.sendproductprice1.Split(' ')[0])*Convert.ToInt32(Form1.sendamount));
```

Comment: Thanks It is simple and It Worked

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, `25 LE` can't be converted to integer like that. You have to separate the number from the text. In this case, you can use

```
var num = Form1.sendproductprice1.Split(' ')[0];
```

which basically takes your input, splits it by spaces and takes the first item from the result. Then this will work

```
Convert.ToInt32(num)*Convert.ToInt32(Form1.sendamount));
```

Comment: Would you need `RemoveEmptyEntries` if the input starts with a white space?

Comment: @Default I think you would. But should I mention all hidden problems of separating a number from a string, it would be a longer answer.

Comment: Just mentioning it since the OPs input *looks* to be a lot of whitespace. none of the other answers here handles it either..

Comment: @Default Hard to tell, there are not even quotation marks around his strings :D

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the number from the string with this code (it allows you to extract the number even if it's not at the beggining)

```
for (int i=0; i< Form1.sendproductprice1.Length; i++)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(Form1.sendproductprice1[i]))
        number += Form1.sendproductprice1[i];
}
```

Then if you do `Convert.ToInt32(number)` it will work just fine

You could also use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to separate the characters from the string to be able to convert the number to integer type.

```
Convert.ToInt32(Form1.sendproductprice1)
```

Will throw an exception if the string has something other than integers.

In your case (in the example you provided) the string is as follows: `"25 LE"`

If the delimeter is always a space then its easy:

```
var test = "25 LE";
var splitted = test.Split(' ');
var digits = splitted[0]; //Will get you the digits only.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle whitespace you can use a `Regex` as well to parse the input

```
string input = "    25 LE ";
Regex regex = new Regex("\\d+");
Match match = regex.Match(input);
if (match.Success)
{
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(match.Value); // number contains 25
}
```